# I am creating a website which enables the end users to create applications, where i will use the user entered value as the database name

Tags: c#

i am retrieving AppName from the Text box.

```
string AppName = TextBox1.Text;
```

Now i want to create a database Whose name will be retrieved from text box, i.e AppName

```
string Text = "create database AppName";  
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Text,Connection);
```

but the above code is creating database named AppName But not the user entered name.

Comment: Could you show us the code where you try to use the user-entered name to create the database?

Answer (score 0):

string Text = "create database " + AppName;

Comment: Please read on how to ask questions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(conn);

Comment: I provided an answer to his question, which was on-topic.

Comment: It was probably down-voted because it's a bad answer.  The world has enough SQL injection vulnerabilities, please don't add more.  Also, the answer provides no context or information.  It just provides a line of (unformatted) code.

Comment: MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(conn);
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

            string AppName = AppNameTextBox.Text;

            string cmdText = "create database" + AppName;
       MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, connection);       Above code is giving an error, "Error in SQL syntax;"

Comment: @user2219632: You forgot the space after the keyword `"database"`, so the resulting query is something like: `create databaseSomeName`.  However, I can't stress enough that this opens up a huge SQL injection vulnerability and *should not* be used.

Comment: @David: Thanks for the help but this is what my website will do. Is this wrong??

Comment: @user2219632: Yes, this is wrong.  It will work, but it will also execute any SQL code anybody enters into the text box.  A malicious user could use this to modify or delete other people's data, gain access to your server, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the actual value in your SQL query, you're just using the same literal string every time:

```
"create database AppName"
```

Instead, you need to incorporate the actual value being entered.  I'm not 100% familiar with the MySQL syntax or query objects, but in general it would look something like this:

```
string appName = TextBox1.Text;
string commandText = "CREATE DATABASE @DBName";
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(commandText, connection))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DBName", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
    cmd.Parameters["@DBName"].Value = appName;

    cmd.Connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

This is free-hand code, since I don't have the relevant objects available.  But the idea is that you would create a variable parameter within the query (`@TableName`) and then populate that parameter with the desired runtime value before executing the query (`cmd.Parameters["@TableName"].Value = appName;`).

Comment: Why's David has being down voted? It seems a solid feedback and answered the question.

Comment: @AwesomeProgrammer: I had some copy/paste problems in the edit history (that's what I get for trying to do too many things at once) so the code wasn't working at first.  (Though it's possible it still doesn't work.  As I said, I don't have the relevant objects in front of me.)  That could be the reason, I suppose.  And the down-voter has a window of opportunity to remove the vote if the answer has been fixed to his satisfaction.  (And if it hasn't, I'd be happy to hear why so the answer could be improved.)

Comment: Do prepared statements work with commands like CREATE? I though there were restrictions to what kinds of statements (or at least what parts of a statement) can be "parametrized", for example you can't make a table name a parameter in a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: @JasonSperske: I'm not sure, to be honest.  It's worth a try, I suppose.  If not then we can still come up with something that sanitizes the input before using it in a query, I'm sure.